# Splitting feature using gaps around in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, splitting

I have a shapefile which has only one feature. I want to separate it into a set of features. these features must be separated using gaps between each feature. How can I do it?

this is its image

[image]

I have used some tools such as erase and diffrence but they don't work because there is only one feature, So I must find a way to split this one feature using gaps into set of feature classes.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

Comment: Your tools of choice http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm

Comment: Just for extra information, QGIS has the same tool as @BERA answered with. found under 'Vectors  >  Geometry Tools  >  Multipart to Singleparts'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ArcGIS try [Multipart To Singlepart](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm):

> Creates a feature class containing singlepart features generated by
>   separating multipart input features

[image]

After that the features will be separated (but still in one feature class).